# System.loadLibrary does not work. UnsatisfiedLinkError for the second lib in chain

Tags: java, java-native-interface, loadlibrary, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java.library.path

I have java program Client.class that uses cpp shared library libclient.so via JNI.
libclient.so is built as shared and uses cpp shared library libhttp.so.

libclient.so and libhttp.so are placed in folder `/home/client/lib64`

Client.class is placed in `/home/client/bin`

Client can load library with

1. System.load and environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. System.loadLibrary and -Djava.library.path

The first way works fine.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /home/client/lib64`

java -classpath ./bin Client

The secon way fails.

`java -classpath ./bin -Djava.library.path=./../lib64 Client`

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/client/lib64/libclient.so: libhttp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I put libhttp.so into /usr/lib64 the second way works fine.

**Why libclient.so is looking for libhttp.so in /usr/lib64 if I use System.loadLibrary?
How can I fix it without coping libhttp.so into /usr/lib64?**

*My loading code:*

```
    //Try load from -Djava.library.path        
    boolean found = false;
    String lib = "client";
    try {
       System.loadLibrary(lib);
       found = true;
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Try load from LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    if (!found) {
       lib = "libclient.so";
       String ld_lib_path = System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
       String[] paths = ld_lib_path.split(":");
       for(int i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
          String p = paths[i];
          File x = new File(p, lib);
          if (x.exists()) {
             System.load(x.getAbsolutePath());
             found = true;
             break;
          }
       }
    }
```

Additional information.

If I test libclient.so with ldd then I see: libhttp.so => not found
If I set export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /home/client/lib64 then I see: libhttp.so => /home/client/lib64/libhttp.so

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that libclient.so is loaded from your JVM, which looks in `java.library.path`. However, when libclient.so tries to load libhttp.so, it knows nothing about Java and just uses the regular Linux way of loading shared libraries (the dynamic linker `ld.so`), which looks in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and some common directories like `/usr/lib64`.

I would probably go with using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set from a start script of your Java application. If you don't want to use a start script, you could in theory set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within the process itself. However, Java does not allow to do this (there is only `System.getenv()`, not `System.setenv()`), so you would need to write a small C library that is called from Java and calls [`putenv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If you build `libclient.so` itself, you can use the `-rpath` linker flag to specify a path where the dynamic linker should look for further required libraries. Be careful if you specify a relative path here, it will interpreted as relative to the current working directory of the running application, not relative to the location of `libclient.so`. To achieve this, you need to use `$ORIGIN` as argument for `-rpath` and be careful that your shell does not expand this.

So, if you want to have `libclient.so` and `libhttp.so` in the same directory, you need to use

```
-rpath '$ORIGIN'
```

as argument to the linker when building `libclient.so`. If you do not call the linker directly but let your compiler call it, you need to add the following to your compiler's command line:

```
-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'
```

More information about this can be found in the [man page for `ld.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so).

Answer (score 2):

I have no good answer for this question.

But I found several good ways.

1. Put libhttp.so into shared location for libraries, for example /usr/lib64.
2. Put path to libhttp.so into LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
3. Build libclient.so with libhttp.so inside.
4. Use -rpath during building of libclient.so.

Answer (score 0):

For correct lookup of library (from *java.library.path*) for different OS's must have different names:

- Linux: *libhttp.so*
- Windows: *http.dll*

Than you can call from Java:

```
System.loadLibrary( "http" );
```