# The netwrok name cannot be found

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface, opencv3.0, jna

I'm trying to run my application from source on another computer using eclipse, where at start it loads the Opencv library dll through `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)`. On the first machine it was working fine, however here it says:

```
java.lang.unsatisfiedLinkError: K:\git\plates\alpr\libs\opencv_java343.dll: the network name cannot be found
```

I'd made 100% sure that the above path already exists. please note that both machines runs Windows 7 64bit OS.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the OS bit version and operating systems match from the original working test and then the non working machine? When native libraries are compiled you will have more then one for multiple os and bit version support.

Comment: @Mr00Anderson thanks for reply, i'd checked that and both machines are almost 100% identical

Comment: It sounds like the API for System.loadLibrary() may be why. A link to an issue likely related. System.loadLibrary() uses "java.library.path". [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215197/system-loadlibrary-does-not-work-unsatisfiedlinkerror-for-the-second-lib-in-cha/16234339) & [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945268/difference-between-using-java-library-path-and-ld-library-path) may help.